# Different values in pandas data frame look equal but are different

Tags: python, pandas

I have a table in which the column called "index_C" and column "index_E" have the same values however when I compare these values using this code

```
comparative_df['comparative_index'] = np.where(comparative_df['index_C']==comparative_df['index_E'], 
                                           'yes', 'no')
```

python says that these values are different. Here the table and the output in the last column

```
print(comparative_df.head())
  index_C Probe_Name_C Bin_Size_C Heigth_Ratio_C index_E Probe_Name_E  \
0       1    01_PLAGL1      156.3            1.0      1   01_PLAGL1   
1       2     02_GRB10      151.8          1.029      2   02_GRB1O.   
2       3      03_MEST      309.8          0.968      3     03_MEST   
3       4      04_MEST      203.2            1.0      4    O04_MEST   
4       5       05_H19      301.0          0.872      5       05H19   

  Bin_Size_E Heigth_Ratio_E comparative_index  
0     156.3         4.000                no  
1      1518         4.029                no  
2     309.8         0.968                no  
3     203.2         4.000                no  
4     301.0         0.872                no
```

I have ensured there are no white spaces using this

```
extracted0 = extracted0.replace(' ', '', regex=True)
```

And converting all values in string applying this

```
.applymap(str)
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Can you print `comparative_df.head().to_dict()`?

Comment: {'index_C': {0: '1', 1: '2', 2: '3', 3: '4', 4: '5'}, 'Probe_Name_C': {0: '01_PLAGL1', 1: '02_GRB10', 2: '03_MEST', 3: '04_MEST', 4: '05_H19'}, 'Bin_Size_C': {0: '156.3', 1: '151.8', 2: '309.8', 3: '203.2', 4: '301.0'}, 'Heigth_Ratio_C': {0: '1.0', 1: '1.029', 2: '0.968', 3: '1.0', 4: '0.872'}, 'index_E': {0: '1\x0c', 1: '2\x0c', 2: '3\x0c', 3: '4\x0c', 4: '5\x0c'}, 'Probe_Name_E': {0: '01_PLAGL1\x0c', 1: '02_GRB1O.\x0c', 2: '03_MEST\x0c', 3: 'O04_MEST\x0c', 4: '05H19\x0c'}, 'Bin_Size_E': {0: '156.3\x0c', 1: '1518\x0c', 2: '309.8\x0c', 3: '203.2\x0c', 4: '301.0\x0c'}, 'Heigth_Ratio_E': {0: ...

Comment: See your problem? You got trailing white spaces but not `' '`. Use `'\s'` in replace instead?

Comment: Worked. MANY thanks Quang Hoang